# Wondering if anybody out here could simplify the highlighted parts of the piece of news

Tags: word-meaning

Three salvage cranes have also arrived at the scene, to raise the ship or move it to another area with weaker currents.Our correspondent at the scene described "an absolutely **desperate development** for the families" as three more bodies were brought in from the **rescue site** on Friday.

What kind of development we call "desperate development"? 
Where is a rescue site? On the shore or in the sea? What happens at a such site?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the highlighted parts paraphrased.

> **desperate development** - there is a development but for the parents, it is very bad development, *reducing their hopes* further (about anyone alive there).

And,

> **rescue site** - the place (site) where the rescue operation is going on.

**After OP's edit:** A rescue site could be on shore, at sea, or a combination of both. It could also be in the middle of a field, or just outside of a mine. Wherever the rescue workers are working, that pretty much defines the area of the rescue site (Thanks, J.R.)

It's about the [Korea ferry tragedy](http://www.aljazeera.com/news/asia-pacific/2014/04/south-korea-ferry-tragedy-death-toll-rises-201441810021531.html), isn't it?

Comment: Since the O.P. asked, I'll add a note of clarification: A rescue site could be on shore, at sea, or a combination of both. It could also be in the middle of a field, or just outside of a mine. Wherever the rescue workers are working, that pretty much defines the area of the rescue site.

Comment: @J.R. Oh, thank you, sir. I din' notice the edit. No notification for editing the question pops up! :(